# Is it possible to check which programs use the battery the most?

Tags: battery

I have a laptop that was advertised that it could run ~17 hours without charging and I only get like 3-4 hours on Ubuntu. I have installed tlp, still the same. Thank you.

Comment: Not even the best laptop computer can run on battery for 17 hours. Depending on the battery in your laptop, 3-4 hours might be all you get.

Answer (score 7):

`powertop` appears to be a useful utility for just the purpose you require.

Install it with `sudo apt install powertop`

Then run it from terminal using `sudo powertop`

Add to that, you can also output the results to an HTML file for easier analysis:
`sudo powertop --html=report.html`

[reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/powertop)